# Don't understand this proof of nonhomogenous Poisson problem (Sobolev space trace and inequality)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

See this proof of existence of solution to nonhomogenous Dirichlet problem (from http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/~frey/cours/UdC/ma691/ma691_ch4.pdf page 7):

[image]

[image]

How is the inequality marked with the red dot derived from the previous inequality? How does manipulate the $\lVert u_g \rVert_{1,\Omega}$ term?

He does say on the line before "For every lift $u_g$", so I guess then $u_g$ is such that its trace is $g$, but otherwise it's an arbitrary member of $H^1$. Then the inequality follows if the infimum is achieved by some $u_g$, but how to show this??

Is there a way to show this inequality without recourse to the infimum norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{K}=\{v\in H^1(\Omega):\ \gamma_0 v=g\}$. Note that $\mathcal{K}$ is a closed convex subset of $H^1(\Omega)$.

Define $F:\mathcal{K}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$F(v)=\|v\|_{1,\Omega}$$

I - $F$ is obviously coercive, i.e. if $\|v\|_{1,\Omega}\to\infty$, $v\in\mathcal{K}$ then, $F(v)\to\infty$.

II - $F$ is also weakly sequentially lower semi continuous,i.e. if $v_n\rightharpoonup  v$ in $\mathcal{K}$ then, $F(v)\le\liminf F(v_n)$.

It follows from I, II and the properties of $\mathcal{K}$, that the infimum of $F$ in $\mathcal{K}$ is attained by some function $u\in\mathcal{K}$.

Comment: Thanks sorry for late acceptance. If the inf is attained, why every book uses inf instead of min?

Comment: I think that the answer is because when we work with $\inf$, we don't have to worry about if it is achieved or not. For example, if you want to take $\min$ in some set of values, you first have to ensure that this minimum does exist, while when you take $\inf$ then, there is no need to know it the $\inf$ does belong to the set or not. To be more specific, in the inequality quoted in your question, note that if the author had used $\min$ instead of $\inf$, then it was necessary for him to first prove the existence of the $\min$.

Comment: I agree, but in this case it is known that the inf $$\inf_{\gamma_0 v = g}\lVert v \rVert_{1,\Omega}$$is attained (you proved it). So books should also know it.

Comment: Re: your latest edit. Hmm, however, his argument as it is is missing detail because he needs to say that the inf is attained for that step to work, right?

Comment: Ok, here is the solution for our problem. Although my solution is correct, it is not the same given by your quote. Indeed, I was rereading his solution and I noted that the inequality before your red dot, works for all $v$ such that $\gamma_0 v=g$, hence, you can just take $\inf$ in both sides. So, although it is a minimum, there is no need to prove it in order to conclude the result.

Comment: Great, it is much easier than thought after all!

Comment: Yes, it is. Your comment in the end of your question, lead me to this tortuous solution. In fact, when I read it I alread posted a solution, because I knew that the infimum is achieved, however, in the solution of this particular problem, there is no need to use such fact.

Comment: lol, sorry to put you through the torture!

Comment: There is no problem. In the end we all learn from this fact.